# Kendo UI MVC cant find KendoNotification widget?

Tags: kendo-ui

Similar to a previous post, but this time Im using MVC and the html helper 
Using Kendo.MVC ver# 2015.1.318.545
and script ui library 2013.3.1324

```
@(Html.Kendo().Notification()
.Name("popupNotification")
)
```

At run time the above results in this code:

```
    <span id="popupNotification"></span><script>
    jQuery(function(){jQuery("#popupNotification").kendoNotification({});});
</script>
```

, in chrome developer tools, I see an error:
***Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).kendoNotification is not a function***

Its strange that I can put in a datepicker in the same spot, but the notification blows chunks.

**[ See reply by user Win below - that was the answer ]**

Comment: Why do you use Script version older than MVC Wrapper? You want to use same version for Kendo.Mvc.dll, kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js and kendo.all.min.js.

Comment: Good question, its an existing project and this probably hasnt been updated.  Ill pull that in and see if that helps

Comment: I see. Ideally, you want to use all 3 files in same version. Otherwise, they will be out of sync.

Comment: That was it!  I just spent the last 3 hours pulling my hair out thinking I had done something wrong.  I see it listed when I look at the included widgets in the newest version, but not the version Im currently on.  Thanks.

Comment: Let me move the comments to answer, so it will help other who has similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you want to use all 3 files (CSS and images too) in same version. Otherwise, they will be out of sync.

- Kendo.Mvc.dll
- kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js
- kendo.all.min.js *(this might vary if you use individual widget)*

***FYI:*** Also make sure that you use Kendo supported jQuery version. New version requires new jQuery version.